# NSString's method 'getCString' return false for Arabic text

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, arabic

I am generating QR code and everything is working fine if text is only in English. When i want to generate QR code with some Arabic text then it fails at NSString's method "getCString:maxLength:encoding:".

Suppose, I have two strings:

```
NSString *englishText = @"Some text English";
NSString *englishArabicMixText = @"Some text بالعربي";

char strEng [[englishText length] + 1];
char strArb [[englishArabicMixText length] + 1];

1- [englishText getCString:strEng maxLength:[englishText length] + 1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
2- [englishArabicMixText getCString:strArb maxLength:[englishArabicMixText length] + 1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

At Case#1 'getCString' return true and QR code is generated and at Case#2 it return false and failed to generate  code.
What should I do, so that in case#2 it should also return true ? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`length` returns the number of Unicode characters. You have to use `lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:`, which returns the number of bytes required to store the receiver in a given encoding.

```
NSUInteger arbLength = [englishArabicMixText lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] + 1;
char strArb [arbLength];
[englishArabicMixText getCString:strArb maxLength:arbLength encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 2):

2 is returning false for either 2 possible reasons:

1) the string cannot be converted with the specified encoding.

2) the buffer to hold the encoded string is too small.

I'd guess (or at least I suggest you to start investigating) problem is nr. 2.

Because as you're converting to UTF8 a single un-encoded character may result in more than one encoded character. An 'A' is a single byte with value 65 but an arabic character or some kind of symbol may require more bytes.

You are assuming your destination buffer requires the same number of bytes as the same number of characters of your NSString

So you should do something like that:

```
NSUInteger size = [englishArabicMixText lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding : NSUTF8StringEncoding];

if(size>0)
{
    size++;

    strArb = malloc(size);  // NOTE: you should allocate space for your string at runtime!!

    [englishArabicMixText getCString:strArb maxLength:size encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

You should do the same for the plain english string too.

And I'd reccomend to allocate dinamically at runtime the space for the C string with malloc and then free it when you don't need it anymore.

Comment: I agree with most of your answer, but using variable length arrays could be better than manually allocating and freeing space.  As long as the string is bounded to some reasonable length.

Comment: the first reason was not causing problem because i already tested using NSString method 'canBeConvertedToEncoding'; it was returning true. Yes, the second one was the issue and it got fixed by getting length of bytes. Thanx